# Is there a way to style the default pdf export from Material Table from MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, export, material-table, export-to-pdf

So far when you export from PDF it comes as the following:

[image]

But I would like to know if is possible to style this in anyway I have a bunch of information that I would like to show:

[image]

I want to show the user information, the student information, the information of the order etc etc etc. is it possible to style it ? I have an example here:

[image]

It shows logo, id, student and user information + the order clearly